# How can i make a dependent dropdown from this google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Google sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1igwlB46ZyeUNOy5jRTNrct5WXSOH9clG/edit#gid=41063263)

I want to make a dependency dropdown from the columns (Division,District, Upazila, Upazila/city corporation, Thana). How can i do this in this sheet?

I tried to categorize the columns as named column and tried INDIRECT function in it
but can't able to make it work

note: I'm a very beginner in excel and google sheets and want to do this in google sheets

Comment: Decide which you are using between Excel and Googlesheets - they are not the same.

Comment: Read and review this article. You will get a video tutorial here. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/207356325?hl=en&msgid=207521644

Answer (score 0):

you can setup Named Ranges from Data->Named ranges (select appropriate data). Once done set up data validation, from Data->Validation. Please test your range and validation until you get the desired result. repeat the same for every column.